# For $X \sim \mathcal{U}[a,b]$, is it true that $E[X^2 \mid A]/E[X \mid A]^2 \le E[X^2 ]/E[X]$ for all $A \subset [a,b]$.

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality

Suppose that $X$ follows a uniform distribution over $[a,b]$, where $a,b>0$. Let $A \subset [a,b]$. Is it true that $$\frac{E[X^2 \mid A]}{E[X \mid A]^2} \le \frac{E[X^2 ]}{E[X]^2}. $$

For my purpose, $A$ can be a union of intervals. I can verify this if $A = \{X\mid X<c\}$, $A = \{X\mid X>c\}$, and $A = \{X\mid X\in[c_0,c_1]\}$ but I am wondering if this is true in general. For example, if $A=[c_0,c_1]\cup[c_2,c_3]$, where $a\le c_0 \le c_1\le c_2\le c_3\le b$, I can write down LHS, but it is hard to evaluate it.

Comment: In that case, $E[X\mid A]^2 = c^2/4$ and $E[X^2 \mid A]=\int_{0}^{c}x^2 dx / c = c^2/3$, so $E[X\mid A]^2/E[X^2 \mid A]=E[X]^2/E[X^2 ]=4/3$ for all $c$. Am I making some mistakes here?

Comment: Sorry, you are right about this case.